# How to determine if a CentOS system is Raid-1?

Tags: centos, raid1

I've tried searching for this answer, but haven't found anything elegant.

I have numerous servers in a colo that is in another state. I need to find a way to check that the servers have RAID-1 on them, so that I can determine if they were setup correctly by my colo.

df -h shows:
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      442G  1.5G  418G   1% /
/dev/sda1              99M   19M   75M  20% /boot
tmpfs                 4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm

however as CentOS uses LVM by default, this doesn't indicate if a RAID-1 is present.

it is supposed to be a software raid, so I'm pretty sure there should be a way to check.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat /proc/mdstat` will give you
    raid usage on your machine

`dmesg | grep raid` will tell you if raid is
    enabled in your kernel

Comment: /proc/mdstat wasn't useful to me for some reason, but the dmesg | grep raid was certainly where I started. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer right after I asked.

dmraid -r should do what I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried that on a few of my software raid machines and it says 'no raid disks' while cat /proc/mdstat does tell me about the raids.

Comment: strange, that's completely backwards for me. I found out from my colo guy that he installed the raids wrong anyways

Answer (score 0):

Hai

when i try this command

[root@localhost ~]# dmraid -r

My result is :

[root@localhost ~]# dmraid -r
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_dhefccahba", GROUP, ok, 976773165 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_dhefccahba", GROUP, ok, 976773165 sectors, data@ 0

What is the meaning of above results